# How to make connection remotely to 3G router if IP of this router is dynamic?

Tags: networking, router, tunnel, 3g

I have computer witch is connected to internet via 3G router (http://www.mobidata.com/en/product/productshow.asp?id=204). IP of 3G router is dynamic. I run server on this computer and want to make client server connection. I don't want to use side of 3G router as client. Is there some solution to make connection? something like tunnel between 3G router and sisco router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a DDNS client that is installed on your either router or your computer to translate the dynamic IP to a fixed domain address. Then you connect to that address instead of an IP.

Don't forget to activate port forwarding for you specific application too.